# My PC shuts down at boot when I installed Debian 11

Tags: debian, dualboot

I am trying to install Debian 11 to bare metal (dual booting with Windows), I have a 100 GB free volume, I used encryption with dm-crypt.

The setup completes fine but when I try to boot it shows me the following errors then the PC shuts down:

[image: Photo of start up errors]

Comment: @OP: So when you are booting Debian, the GUI crashes and it then immediately proceeds to shut down, is that correct? Are you booting using GRUB? If so, can you successfully boot to text mode by appending " 3" to the kernel command line?

Answer (score 0):

So I discovered the issue for everyone having the same problem in future.
The problem I had was because of having two GPU without driver installed. I hoped into the UEFI settings and change it from switchable graphics to discrete graphics, effectively disabling the second GPU. then I installed and signed the drivers of the second one. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Easier in the long run, and more trustworthy is to remove the 2nd card from the system until the drivers are installed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).